# Maven package works wrong with Tomcat: Maven package places .war and WEB-INF inside target, Tomcat looks for it in the root

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, servlets

I have a test project that contains a single `index.jsp` page and a single `TestServlet.java`. I try to package it using Maven and deploy it on Tomcat. I have this directory structure:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijXu3.png
```

**TestServlet.java:**

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("It's me");
        //response.getWriter().println("<p>Hello world</p>");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Test.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testmavenbuild</groupId>
    <artifactId>testmavenbuild</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I run Maven's command package and get a **testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war** file and a **testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT** folder that contains an empty META-INF folder and a WEB-INF folder:

```
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojv4S.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbazU.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0NuI.png
```

At the same time, package command gives this output:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM1Id.png
```

The **problem** is, that I can't access a servlet. I go to `http://localhost:8080/TestMavenBuild` and I can see the index.jsp just fine. But that's because the index.jsp has always been in the project root to begin with. However when I go to `http://localhost:8080/TestMavenBuild/Test.do`, I get a **404 Not Found error**.

I can fix the error by manually taking the WEB-INF from inside `root/target/testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT` and copypasting it inside root. Then after restarting Tomcat, the servlet works just fine (Meaning, that I can see the "Hello World" output).

I've read some Maven guides and they don't seem to be touching on this problem. Tomcat seems to only look for `WEB-INF` inside the `tomcat/webapps/root` folder. It can't find it inside `tomcat/webapps/root/target/testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT`. It seems that the solution should include copypasting the `WEB-INF` from `root/target/testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT` into the `root` *or* copypasting `testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` from `root/target` into the `roo`t. I could write a script that would do just that, but I'm unsure what's the convencional approach is.

PS Don't have enough reputation to add pictures directly, if someone could replace the links with images, it would be awesome.

Comment: 2 things. 1. Have you tried by putting your war name after host. Mean localhost:8080/<war nam>/servlet path. 2 update your servlet path name to root.war and remove existing root folder from webapps folder and put this war in it then try.

Comment: @Psingh Is it a way of asking if Maven has placed the .war/war-folder inside `tomcat/webapps`? No, it didn't. And thus `http://localhost:8080/testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Test.do` or `http://localhost:8080/testmavenbuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/Test.do` don't work. The second option feels like a worse fix than me writing a simple bash script that would copypaste WEB-INF into root. I don't want to get rid of my root folder; neither does any Maven/servlets guide tells I should. I want to do things the way developers usually do them, follow a best practice.

Comment: In tomcat, if the war file have name root.war then it goes with “/“ as contextpath. However if you want to have some context path then one of the convenient way is to name your war file with that value. Refer link, they have provided various ways to deploy application in tomcat. Even with  maven plugins too https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war.